# SQLite : get the files without extension from a column containing file names

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column (file_name) containing file names in the File table.

I want to get all the files without extension from the table with SQLite.

One way to do it is to select all file names except those with extension (I did  not tried it yet) but I am wondering if there is a more straight forward way without using Set operators?

Thanks,

Comment: What's "Set operators" you're refering to? You want something that behaves like `select * from file where file_name not like '%.%'` but in a different way? If so, why and how different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c398c/3)

You can simply use the following select statement:

```
select * from filenames
where filename NOT LIKE '%.%' OR filename LIKE '.%'
```

This select statement selects files without extension plus special files like .profile etc.

EDIT:

if the version of your sqllite supports regex, you can use the following:

```
select * from filenames
where filename NOT LIKE '%.%' OR filename LIKE '.%' AND  filename REGEXP '^([^.]+)$'
```

Comment: Yes, but it will not fetch file names without extension but having dots in their path